# How to best store a list of primitive values?

Tags: java

In my Java program, I want to store a list of primitive values. I could do something like this:

```
int x = 0;
double timestamp = 123.1d;
List<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();
data.add(x);
data.add(timestamp);
```

But then the problem is that I do not know exactly what kind of objects i store in the list. So is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Why not using two lists ?

Comment: Because there can be an arbitrary amount of primitive values.

Comment: To be honest, I gave up and wrote specialized versions of an ArrayList for all primitive types. So I got `DoubleArray` and you could just add ints to it.

Comment: you can use wrapper class instead primitive datatype like Interger instead of int. If you want to use wrapper then i have solution for your problem.

Comment: @subhashlamba: he's *already* using wrapper classes. The compiler auto-boxes the primitive values automatically.

Comment: This is one of those cases where upcasting is not a good idea. Safer  and robust solution - Do as Kocko says seperate lists. maybe a list of lists where you will be knowing that the first list is of ints, second is of doubles etc.

Comment: @WhoAmI Separate lists are possible given he doesn't rely on order of elements. If he does then separate lists would be very complicated. Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23243862/2709026

Comment: @close voters: Imho, this i not a duplicate! I want to store different primitive data types in a list and not only ints.

Comment: I also do not think this is a duplicate, it is about having different types in the List, not about just using a wrapper class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `Double`, `Integer`, `Long` all belong to the `Number`-class. So a

```
List<Number>
```

would probably fit. It is exactly what it is - a `List` of numbers of unspecified subtype. Because of autoboxing you should be able to just add the primitives, but the better practice would be to use the Wrapper-classes.

The `Number`-class offers methods to get the different representations of the `Number`, for example [doubleValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29). So you could convert all the values in the `List<Number>` to (as an example) `Double`s by using this method. For more reference see the [Oracle documentation for Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

Comment: yes.. But you'll have to downcast when you get the value back. And if the numbers(of ints, longs, shorts, doubles etc) are arbitrary,  you could end up casting a double into a short

Comment: for that case Object would be best which can accomodate anything and later downcasting based on the type

Comment: @WhoAmI well if you want to store different subclasses of a class in one data structure of one type this will be unavoidable.

Comment: @WhoAmI The Number class offers you methods to get the Number in the idfferent formats so you do not loose anything by just using these to convert to the type you need.

Comment: @susheel No. Why should we use Object if we know that it are Numbers? Number even offers us helper methods to deal with exactly this problem, because Number exists for this purpose. A List<Object> that can only contain Numbers is really bad design.

Comment: if we know that its all numbers then its not a problem. he was talking about mixed content i felt

Answer (score 2):

You could use `List<Object>` and add any kind of object to it.While retrieving the Object back from `List<Object>` you can get class of object by `list.get(0).getClass()` or you could check  for `list.get(i) instacne of  Double`.

Answer (score 1):

use wrapper class and use **instance of** operator to check datatype of value. 
like

```
Integer x = 0;
Double timestamp = 123.1d;
List<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();
data.add(x);
data.add(timestamp);
if(data.get(0) instance of Integer)
{
...
}
else if(data.get(0) instance of Double )
{
..
}
```